# In an iPad SplitView, how do I add a Date Picker control to the Root View?

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder, ipad

I'm diving into iPhone OS development on the iPad and one of the things I'm playing with is the SplitView template.  The template provides a window with a UISplitView view, containing the Root View (on the left of the window) and the Detail View (on the right of the window).  The Root View is a subclass of a TableView.  Rather than having the entire Root View consist of a TableView, I'd like it to contain a DatePicker view along with the TableView under it.  When I go into IB and try and drop a DatePicker into the Root View, it won't let me.  It will only let me add a DatePicker view to the Detail View.

1. Why wont IB let me drop a DatePicker view into the Root View?
2. How can I add a DatePicker to the RootView in addition to the TableView?

I'm still learning this new platform, so I apologize if these questions are absurd in any way.  Thanks so much in advance for your help, I'm going to continue researching these questions right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why wont IB let me drop a DatePicker
>   view into the Root View?

For starters, RootViewController is a UITableView. You can't add a UIDatePicker to a UITableView.

> How can I add a DatePicker to the
>   RootView in addition to the TableView?

If you want to add a UIDatePicker, you have to replace RootViewController with a UIViewController then add a UITableView and UIDatePicker.

Comment: Thanks, Jordan, that makes sense.  I removed the RootViewController and dropped in a UIViewController.  That allowed me to add either a UITableView or a UIDatePicker, but not both.  Does that sound right or am I still missing something?